# C# Exception Listener

Tags: c#, exception, callback

C# Question. Arbitrary class `Class` has method `Foo()`, a method which can throw an exception.  Is there some way to add a private callback mechanism `bar()` to `Class`, such that if `Foo()` throws an exception, `bar()` execution will be triggered **before** the throw keeps going up the chain? If that can't happen, what about after the exception is caught?

-- Edit --

Since some of the initial comments are "this is confusing what are you doing dude" I'll address it further.

The reason I would like an exception listener is because I have some publicly readable boolean state about class `Class`, which I want to be set to true whenever an exception has been thrown. Since there could be potentially multiple functions within `Class` which throw exceptions, I don't want to do the boiler plate work of setting hasError to true each time an exception is thrown.  Automate, baby.

So our interface, and main function are:

```
public interface IObjectProvider
{
    IEnumerable<object> Allobjects { get; }
}

public interface IContext
{
    delegate bool ContextIsStillValid(object o);
    delegate void Run(object o);
}

// main program
public static void Main() {
    IContext context = initcontext(...);
    IObjectProvider objectProvider = initobjectprovider(...);

    // ...program executes for awhile...

    foreach(var obj in objectProvider.AllObjects)
    {
        if(context.ContextIsStillValid(obj))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Run(obj);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // log the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, we specify some `IContext` which will 'Run' using some `object`, *if and only if* that `IContext` first successfully passes a 'Validation' check using that same `object`.  Fine.  Now, a common variation of implementation for `IContext` is the following (take my word, it is):

```
public class Class : IContext {

    private bool _hasError = false;

    // so our validation check is implemented with an internal flag. 
    // how is it set?
    public bool ContextIsStillValid = (o) => !_hasError;

    public void Run = 
    (o) =>
    {
        string potentially_null_string = getstring(...);
        if(potentially_null_string == null) 
        { 
            // our internal flag is set upon the need to throw an exception
            this._hasError = true; 
            throw new Exception("string was null at wrong time"); 
        }

        Global.DoSomethingWith(potentially_null_string.Split(',');
    };
}
```

Here, we've demonstrated a common implementation of `IContext`, such that once the `Run` method throws a single `Exception`, the `Run` method should become unreachable due to `IsContextStillValid` subsequently always returning false.

Now imagine that there are other Exception-throwing calls within our implementation of `Run(object)`. The problem is that every time we want to throw a new exception, we have to duplicate code to the effect of `_hasError = true; throw new Exception(...);`.  Ideally, an exception listener would resolve this issue for us, and I am curious if any of you know how to implement one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? can't you just use a try catch and a rethrow? seems like an odd question...

Comment: Why not just put a `try/catch` in `Foo()` which invokes `bar()` in the `catch` block and then re-throws?

Comment: You could technically use an exception filter on a catch block to observe the exception before the call stack unwinds. See the SO doc on [exception filters](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/46/exception-filters) for an example.

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I have some boolean state about class `Class` that I want to be set to true whenever an exception has been thrown, basically some `hasError` state.  Since there could be potentially multiple functions within `Class` which throw exceptions, I don't want to do the boiler plate work of setting hasError to true each time an exception is thrown.  Automate, baby.

Comment: @David because there are going to be multiple calls within `Foo()` which may cause an error, and it is likely to become a maintenance headache if a developer becomes responsible for adding boilerplate code to drive the internal state each time a new update is added.  @mike z thanks I'll look into that.  @gilmishal please look at my edits, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            //Execute some code that might fail
        }
        catch
        {
            bar();
            throw;
        }
    }
    private void bar()
    {
        //do something before throwing
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that one also needs to consider the fact that execution of bar() itself could throw an error.

Comment: True, it all depends on what you are doing and how you want it to behave.

Comment: @CavanPage thanks Cavan, this suggestion has already been made, this suggestion might work, I appreciate your input.